# Error using guestmount to mount windows qcow2 image

Tags: windows, openstack, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

my os is **centos** 7.4

```
root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

**kernel version**: 3.10.0

```
root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ uname -r
3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
```

Here is my mount command and error prompt， `use guestmount -m /dev/sda1`

> root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ guestmount -a win2016
>   --ro -m /dev/sda1 /mount libguestfs: error: mount: unsupported filesystem type guestmount: '/dev/sda1' could not be mounted.
>   guestmount: Did you mean to mount one of these filesystems?
>   guestmount:     /dev/sda1 (ntfs) guestmount:     /dev/sda2 (ntfs)

here is use guestmount -m /dev/sda2

> root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ guestmount -a win2016
>   --ro -m /dev/sda2 /mount libguestfs: error: mount: unsupported filesystem type guestmount: '/dev/sda2' could not be mounted.
>   guestmount: Did you mean to mount one of these filesystems?
>   guestmount:     /dev/sda1 (ntfs) guestmount:     /dev/sda2 (ntfs)

-m /dev/sda report error , so i use -i to guestmout, but also error

> root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ guestmount -a win2016
>   --ro -i /mount guestmount: no operating system was found on this disk
>   If using `guestfish '-i'` option, remove this option and instead
>   use the commands 'run' followed by 'list-filesystems'.
>   You can then mount filesystems you want by hand using the
>   'mount' or 'mount-ro' command.
>
> If using `guestmount '-i'`, remove this option and choose the
>   filesystem(s) you want to see by manually adding '-m' option(s).
>   Use 'virt-filesystems' to see what filesystems are available.
>
> If using other virt tools, this disk image won't work
>   with these tools.  Use the guestfish equivalent commands
>   (see the virt tool manual page).

the libguestfs-winsupport and *ntfs* are all installed.

```
root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ rpm -qa | grep winsupport
libguestfs-winsupport-7.2-2.el7.x86_64
root@wllabs:/home/wllabs/instances/image2016$ rpm -qa | grep ntfs
ntfs-3g-devel-2017.3.23-1.el7.x86_64
ntfsprogs-2017.3.23-1.el7.x86_64
ntfs-3g-2017.3.23-1.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing the same behavior..

According the documentation, this is normal behavior.
They removed ntfs support starting from RHEL/CentOS 7.3.
More info on: http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#mount:-unsupported-filesystem-type-with-ntfs-in-rhel-7.2

It is possible to compile your own libguestfs which supports ntfs, but this is not supported.
I haven't tested it yet, but this thread mentions the steps.
https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2016-February/msg00145.html

I hope this helps since this is my first post. :-)

Kind regards,

Jeff